# How to construct a point $P_3=(x_3,y_3)$, that is perpendicular to a line $\overline{P_1P_2}$?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I have a line drawn between two points: $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$.

I'm trying to think of an algorithm to determine a point $P_3=(x_3,y_3)$, which is perpendicular to the line $\overline{P_1P_2}$.

My idea so far is:
Draw a line between $P_2$ and $P_3$:
 $\overline{P_2P_3}$.  That line has to be perpendicular to $\overline{P_1P_2}$.
The length of $\overline{P_2P_3}$ is irrelevant, as long as it lies perpendicular to $\overline{P_1P_2}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By algorithm do you mean a general formula? Like the way $m(x-x_1)=y-y_1$ is the formula of a line?

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt yes, or the formulas required to get the answer

Comment: How can a point be perpendicular to a line? Is that really what you want to ask?

Comment: @P.Siehr i'm sorry, allow me to rephrase: i want to calculate a point, (p3) which is the endpoint of a line perpendicular to p1-p2, starting from p2

Comment: I'm sorry as well. I couldn't think of a task, requiring the construction of such a point. Hence, my confusion. Both answers already explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$ you can choose $C:=(x_2+y_1-y_2,y_2-x_1+x_2)$.
This come from the fact that vectors $\alpha=(a,b)$ and $\beta=(c,d)$ are normal iff $ac+bd=0$ so an easy-to-find normal vector to $(a,b)$ is $(-b,a)$. Notice that the vector distance between two points is calculated simply by doing the componentwise difference.

Comment: this actually worked, and also is way more simple than the other answers given thank you!

Comment: Yes, that works, because it is the same answer as the others. But it is not simple. Have you really understood what Tancredi did there? I doubt that you can explain that to your friends.

Comment: Actually I think it's not the same answer (obviously the line is unique so every correct answer gives the same line). You are right although, the answer is less easy to understand, but it is much more simple than the others.
What follows the formula in my comment is an invitation - given the solution FrankK was searching for - to think about hit, with two hints.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ denote the gradient of a straight line. Then $-\frac{1}{m}$ must be the gradient of the line perpendicular to the line with gradient $m$, hence, the gradient of a perpendicular line is given by: $$\implies -\frac{1}{m}=-\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{y_1-y_2}\right)$$

In addition, let $A$ and $B$ be the points such that $$A(x_1,y_1)$$ and $$B(x_2,y_2)$$Given this, the midpoint of these two points are given by $$mid_{AB}=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$$Using these two ideas, do you think you can figure out how to find the given equation for $P_3$?

Comment: i don't understand the midpoint part, what is that good for?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want one line to be a perpendicular bisector of another (i.e. one line divides another line straight down the middle and is perpendicular to it) then that line must travel through the midpoint of the line connecting the two points.

Comment: i dont really get it to be honest, could you incude the equation in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Given : $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$ with $x_1\ne x_2$

the slope of the line between these point is $m=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$

and the line passing thorough $P_2$ and $P_3$ has slope: $m'=\frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}$

the two lines are perpendicular if $m'=-\frac{1}{m}$.

Can you do from this?

---

so the slope of $P_2P_3$ is:
$$
m'=-\frac{1}{m} \quad \iff \quad \frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}=-\frac{x_1-x_2}{y_1-y_2}
$$

If the distance $\overline{P_2P_3}$ is not relevant you can fix one of the coordinates of $P_3$ ( $x_3$ or $y_3$) and find the other.

Note that all this is valid only if $P_1P_2$ is not parallel to one of the coordinate axis.

Comment: so, the slope of p2-p3 = - (y1-y2) / (x1-x2) ?

Comment: but my previous statement is correct?

Comment: I've adde to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> i dont really get it to be honest, could you incude the equation in your answer?

As this was a bit too much for a comment, I formulated this as addition to @joshuaheckroodt's answer. 
Please accept his answer, and give both an upvote - if that helped you.

Here is a picture:

[image]

([source of the original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope#/media/File:Wiki_slope_in_2d.svg))

The idea is to construct a linear function $$f(x) = \tilde{m}x+\tilde{c},$$
the red line, that is perpendicular to the orange line $\overline{P_1P_2}$.

Such a linear function has two variable $\tilde{m}$ and $\tilde{c}$ to be uniquely defined. Hence, we need two informations.

**Slope**
The slope is given by $$\tilde{m}=-\frac{1}{m},$$
where $m$ is the slope of the orange line.

I can't think of a way to explain that, but with vectors.

Given a vector $v=(x,y)$. Then the vector $\tilde{v}:=(-y,x)$ is orthogonal to $v$, because: $$\langle v,\tilde{v}\rangle = x\cdot(-y)+y\cdot x=0.$$
Here $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the scalar product.
The slope of $v$ is $\frac{y}{x}$, and the slope of $\tilde{v}$ is $\frac{-x}{y}$.

**Intersection with the $y$-axis**
We also need to determine the value of $\tilde{c}$. And here @joshua makes a choice:
The linear function should go through the midpoint $P_{mid}=(x_{mid},y_{mid})$ of the line $\overline{P_1P_2}$.

With that information you can determine $\tilde{c}$ through: 
$$y_{mid} = \tilde{m}x_{mid}+\tilde{c}.$$

Does that help?